# Access both tails of the normal CDF in a single call of pnorm

Tags: c++, r

I'm writing an R package in which I need to evaluate multiple times the (log of the) normal CDF `Phi(.)` for each entries of a very large matrix `A` (e.g., 5000 x 20000), and do this accurately for both tails, i.e., `log(Phi(A))` and `log(1-Phi(A))`.

So far, I have been using the R function `pnorm` twice

```
logphiA <- pnorm(A, log.p = TRUE)
log1_phiA <- pnorm(A, log.p = TRUE, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

which is quite expensive. Note that I can't use the cheaper and less accurate version for `log1_phiA`:

```
log1_phiA <- log(1-exp(logphiA))
```

as this causes stability issues in my case.

I've looked up the C++ implementation of `pnorm` and I saw that it calls a void function `pnorm_both` which can compute both tails at once and is used within the function `pnorm5`, see e.g. [here](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/cxxr/doc/html/Rmath_8h_source.html). So I was wondering whether this could be a cheaper option of me, provided I can call it within my R code. Do you know if this is an option? Or should I copy the C++ sources and modify the `pnorm_both` function accordingly?

Or else, would you have another idea for a faster evaluation of the normal CDF, without giving up computational accuracy?

Thanks!

Comment: The algorithm for calculating the tails accurately is expensive. I doubt overhead is the issue at all, so re-implementing or changing the C code probably won't help. I suspect you can only increase the speed (in the general case) if you sacrifice accuracy. However, maybe `log1_phiA_1 <- log(-expm1(logphiA))` would be sufficiently accurate?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Roland. OK I will run some tests with `expm1` and see how the algorithm behaves.